# Regarding 50ohm Impedance control trace

Tags: layout

We have the query regarding Stack up, 50-ohm Impedance traces and its Reference Layers.

Recently We want to fabricate 6 layers 50-ohm impedance controlled board. but in this PCB We have to Routed 50 Ohm Impedance traces on Layers L1, L3, L4, and L6.

And we are providing L2 - GND Layer and L5 - POWER as a reference Layer for all above Layers.

So we want to know that if 50 Ohm impedance traces are on L6 Layer then its reference layer is L5 which is POWER Layer.

Will it affect our 50 Ohm impedance traces or it will take reference from L2 (GND) layer?

Or we have to change Layer L5 to GND to provide reference Layer to L6?

Let us know if you required more information regarding our query.

Answer (score 0):

If you have distributed vias and low ESR caps over a broad range  then the Vcc to Vdd impedance will be the difference. This ought to be < 1 Ohm and your controlled impedance tolerance is <= 10% with testing.